# migrating from rails 4.2 to 5 issue need to downgrade ActiveRecord version to work with 1 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to migrate from Rails 4.2 to 5 and we have a gem called activerecord-tableless and it is not compatible with ActiveRecord 5.x so is there a way in which I can downgrade ActiveRecord version as it is not a part of Gemfile and is a core Rails dependency.
Or I will have to look for a gem that does the same job as tableless and compatible with ActiveRecord 5.x

I would rather not find another gem but any advise on this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a maintained and improved fork of `activerecord-tableless` called `activerecord-tablefree` that supports Rails 5.x and is actively maintained

https://github.com/pboling/activerecord-tablefree

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much